# Почему приложение из консоли выдаёт ошибку,а из IDE все работает?

Tags: linux, алгоритм, файлы, golang

Когда запускаю код из IDE Goland все отрабатывает, как и задумано, но когда компилирую и запускаю из консоли выходит ошибка

```bsh
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 274 [running]:
main.parseDataInStdout(0xc4200780c0, 0xc42005a120, 0xc420078120)
    /root/go/src/netflow/main.go:150 +0xb7f
main.main.func1(0xc4200780c0, 0xc42005a120, 0xc420078120, 0xc420018190)
    /root/go/src/netflow/main.go:69 +0x3f
created by main.main
    /root/go/src/netflow/main.go:68 +0x240
```

Сначала я подумал,что запускаю слишком много дескрипторов, но увеличив значение в */etc/security/limit.conf* ничего не изменилось.
Вот сам код, который запускает 288 горутин ,известно точное количество файлов которые нужно обработать. Предполагаю,что у меня может быть ошибка в самом коде и хотелось бы узнать как файлы обработать не все за раз а отдельными кусками.

```
var numThread = 288
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(numThread)
        for i := 0; i < numThread;i++{
                        go func() {
                                parseDataInStdout(done,cmdSlice,reports)
                                wg.Done()
                        }()
                }


        go func() {
                wg.Wait()
                close(reports)
        }()
```

По возможности хотелось бы услышать совет как ещё возможно ускорить обработку

```
func parseDataInStdout(done <-chan struct{},cmnd <-chan string,r chan<- Report){

        sliceStr := []string{}

        for c := range cmnd{
                cmd := exec.Command("sh", "-c", c)
                output, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println(err)
                }
                if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
                        fmt.Errorf("RunCommand: cmd.Start(): %v", err)
                }
                scanner := bufio.NewScanner(output)
                outData := []string{}
                scanner.Split(bufio.ScanLines)
                for scanner.Scan(){
                        outData = append(outData,scanner.Text())
                }
                // вырезать с 10 по 24
                var purgeData = [14]string{}; var crdIdx = 0
                for i := 9; i < 23;i++{
                        purgeData[crdIdx] = outData[i]
                        crdIdx++
                }
                for _, t := range purgeData{
                        str := parseData(t)
                        sliceStr = append(sliceStr,str)
                }
                select {
                case r <- Report{parseInt(sliceStr[0])}:
                case <-done:
                                        return
                }

        }

}
```

Comment: А какая строка в последнем куске кода соответствует линии 150 в main.go?

Comment: @kostix `purgeData[crdIdx] = outData[i]` в данном месте, при запуске из консоли выдаёт ошибку, но запуская через IDE все работает и выводит результат

Comment: Ещё вопросы: 1) а IDE сказано что-нибудь писать этой программе на stdin? 2) что если запустить как `$ ./program </dev/null` ? 3) надо прилепить отладочный вывод перед этой сторокой, чтобы она напечатала `crdIdx`, `i`, `len(purgeData)`, `len(outData)`.

Comment: @kostix Решил данную проблему тем, что углубился в каналы и горутины и отредактировал код